# Microsoft Access : How can I get creation date of row?

Tags: ms-access, timestamp, row, creation

I have an access database created from 7 years ago.

Unfortunately, tables didn't have time stamp column :(

**Is there any way to be able to know the creation date for each row in a specific table ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you have a time stamp you created yourself, there is no way to find this information.

Is it possible that you have some old back-ups? That might help narrow it down.