# There is a MS Access internal timestamp for updates/creations?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm looking to fetch everything in a MS Access database but only rows from a given timestamp and there is no timestamps attributes by default.

Someone told me that there is an internal timestamp for updates/creation in MS Access but I can't find something about that.

ps: The database is read-only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based off of the information here: [Microsoft Access : How can I get creation date of row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15613067/microsoft-access-how-can-i-get-creation-date-of-row), the answer to your question is no.

It seems Access doesn't keep track of when a timestamp was created.  You need to have your own system implemented.